# How can I read 32 bits at once in Assembly x86?

Tags: assembly, fread

I have to read 4 characters at once from a binary opened file so I can apply a XOR with a double defined variable.I've open the file in binary read and when I apply the XOR it changes every byte .I think that my program actually takes every byte at a turn ,not a 4 byte-block.How can I read 4 at once?

```
buffer dd 0    
rmode db "rb",0    
rfilename db "input.txt"   
key dd 0Ah
.....................................................................
;open the file    
    push offset rmode
    push offset rfilename
    call fopen
    add esp ,8

    push eax
    push 1
    push 1
    push offset buffer
read_loop:
    call fread    
    test eax,eax    
    jz close_file       

    MOV ebx,key
    XOR buffer,eax
 ............................................
```

For the input

```
 0123
```

I get :

```
:;89
```

But it should be

```
0129
```

Comment: Assembly for what? Casting my mind back, for CPU's with 32-bit data bus there is usually a few read commands to read (for example) bit, byte, word, longword, something like `read`, `read.w`, `read.l` etc. but you'd have to RTFM for your system.

Comment: 32-bits processor x86

Comment: Is this an assembly system call to the fread() function? In which case you need to read N bytes where N is the number of bytes in 32-bits, very likely to be 4. I'm very rusty on asm and zero xp with x86 so by all means wait for an adult to answer.

Comment: Yes,I've added to the stack the stream ,size,count and the variable buffer and the call the fread function

Comment: As @JohnU said, you are only reading 1 byte not 4. You `push 1` for item size instead of 4. Also note that x86 is little endian, so your key of `0ah` will change the first byte, not the 4th.

Comment: I've tried with pushing 1 for number of items and 4 for size ,and for the same input : 0123 I get this on output : š

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see at least a couple of problems.

In general, when you do a call, you have to push then "forget" the data. You do it right for the `fopen` call, but not the `fread`.

Then somehow you want to read 4 bytes, but you `push 1` as the size... You probably want to `push 4` as the size and `push 1` for the number of items. That way you can keep the simple `test eax,eax` to break the loop (although that way you are NOT checking for errors: i.e. `eax = -1`). SO this:

```
read_loop:       ; <- move loop here
  push eax
  push 1
  push 4         ; <- use 4 to read 4 bytes
  push offset buffer
  call fread
  add esp, 16    ; <- forget the push'es
  test eax,eax
  jz close_file
```

Next, you get the key in `ebx`, then do the `xor` with `eax`

```
MOV ebx,key
XOR buffer,eax   ; <- shouldn't this be ebx?
```

Since `fread` returns the size, doing the `xor` with `eax` is certainly wrong.

A side note: `fread` will fail if there are only 1, 2, or 3 digits left in the file. You can circumvent that by swapping the `push 1` and `push 4` and then check the return value to know how many character were read... that's a bit more work!

Comment: Yes ,I cleaned the stack from the call to fread ,but I didn't post the whole code .I just needed to find out how I can read 4 bytes.And yes,it should be    XOR buffer ,ebx     ,my mistake

Comment: I've tried with pushing 1 for number of items and 4 for size ,and for the same input : 0123 I get this on output : š

Comment: You do not show the code you use to print out the data. Note that if you have 4 characters in a register, you first have to convert that to a string. Also, the `XOR` may transform the characters into something that cannot be printed correctly. One way to test (at least know more) is to comment out the XOR and see what you get in that case. If `0123` then we know the XOR causes the problem.

Comment: Yes,the problem was at printing the data .I've read 4 bytes ,but only printed 1 .I've changed that and it works.